# groupedbar in StatsPlots(Julia) modifies the input array weirdly

Tags: julia, bar-chart

I am encountering a strange issue! I am trying to plot using groupedbar but I facing this strange issue. here is the code to generate the data and plot it:

```
nam = string.(repeat(1:20, outer=2))
sx = repeat(["Pre-Polarization", "Post-Polarization"], inner = 20)
c = 1:40
groupedbar(nam, c, group = sx, xlabel = "Groups", ylabel = "Scores",
        title = "Scores by group and category", bar_width = 0.9,
        lw = 0, framestyle = :box)
```

And I get the following results:

[image]

Does anybody know the reason it's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the X axis values look strange is the Julia is sorting the numbers as strings, not as numbers.  This means, for example, that "3" > "20" in your code for nam.

To fix this you should not stringify nam before it is plotted.  So use

```
nam = repeat(1:20, outer=2)
```

in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If strings are required, you can exploit the fact that space comes before numbers in lexicographical sort, such that `" 3" < "10"`

For example:

```
nam = (repeat(1:20, outer=2))

# Space sorts before numbers
nam = [ n >= 20 ? "$n" : 
        n >= 10 ? " $n" :
        "  $n" 
        for n in nam]

sx = repeat(["Pre-Polarization", "Post-Polarization"], inner = 20)
c = 1:40
groupedbar(nam, c, group = sx, xlabel = "Groups", ylabel = "Scores",
    title = "Scores by group and category", bar_width = 0.9,
    lw = 0, framestyle = :box)
```

[image: A grouped bar chart showing two groups of steadily increasing values. The values on the x axis are ordered correctly.]

The keen-eyed observer might notice a slight misalignment of the numbers now. This can be fixed by using either [U+200B Zero Width Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/) or an [U+2063 Invisible Seperator](https://unicode-table.com/en/2063/) in place of the regular space, though it would make the code harder to read.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the order of the groups by myself rather than automatically organized?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, hence the hack